# Facebook dialog apps

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, dialog

I have created an application for Facebook, but I want show all content in a dialog box like Facebook style. How? like this http://www.bigthink.it/wp-content/uploads/2010/06/fb-dialog-box.jpg

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not clear. What content do you want to show? What type of dialog? Do you have any code that you can share?

If you just want to wrap some content in a fb-like dialog, then you can use the [javascript sdk](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/) method *FB.Dialog.create*, it's not officially documented (as far as I'm aware), but it works.

Here's an example of use:

```
var fbDialog = null,
    html = '<img src="http://www.bigthink.it/wp-content/uploads/2010/06/fb-dialog-box.jpg"/>',
    params = {
        display: "iframe",
        content: html,
        loader: true,
        closeIcon: true,
        visible: true,
        onClose: function() {
            FB.Dialog.remove(fbDialog);
        }
    }

fbDialog = FB.Dialog.create(params);
```

Comment: For example... an user go to my application url.. apps.facebook.com/testappexample and the application show the autorize permission..ok..after that, the application open a dialog box like facebook with my content like iframe inside. Do you have skype dear?

Comment: No, no skype. Are you saying that you want to load all of the content of your app in a fb-like dialog? It does not work like that, when someone goes into your application facebook POSTs some data into an iframe with your canvas url (the one you supply in the app setttings). Because of that the content of your app will be rendered inside that iframe, there's nothing you can do about that. You can however control how the content looks inside that iframe, which is your canvas page, there you can load what ever you want into bf-like dialogs as I showed you.